# Bilinear form as sum of square products

Tags: linear-algebra

On the "Numerical methods for ordinary differential equations" by Butcher, there's the following statement:

A quadratic form of inner products

$\sum_{i,j=1}^{s} m_{i,j} \langle U_i,U_j \rangle$

is equal to

$\sum_{l=1}^{s} ||\sum_{i=1}^{s} \mu_{li} U_i||^2$

Additional useful information are that $M$ is a symmetric semi-definite positive matrix, so that

$x^T M x = \sum_{i=1}^{s} (x^T \mu_i)^2$

where $\mu_{il}$ is the matrix given by right eigenvectors of $M$, where the columns are multiplied for the corresponding eigenvalue.

I don't really know where to start to prove that.